# Trying to build an ASP.NET Core API within a .NETFramework application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to build a .net core API using MVC, but I am trying to add it to an application that was not build on ASP.NET Core. When I try and configure the interfaces to be used in the core app (Setup.cs) I am not able to reference the interface. When trying reference the solution within the core app, I get the error

"The following projects are not supported as references: [solution name] has target frameworks that are incompatible with the targets in current project.

.NETCoreApp,Version=1.0
.NETFramework,Version=v4.5

What is the best way to be able to reference a .NETFramework project within a .NETCore project?

Comment: You can't reference an assembly that is higher than the framework of the referencing assembly (you can go down, though).  In other words, a ASP.NET Core project could reference a .NET 4.6 project.

Comment: Is that not what I am attempting to do? Within my ASP.NET Core project, I want to reference a project in .NET 4.5? Is that not down referencing?

Comment: Just because you're using the ASP.NET Core application framework doesn't mean you're building on .NET Core.

Comment: Ah, I misread the direction, sorry.  This should work, though there may be a trick to referencing non .NET Core assemblies in .NET Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from comment above I realized it was not possible. I was not able to use the .net standard version in my core app.

Comment: Version 4.7.1 is the first version of the full .NET Framework that supports the .NET Standard 2.0 specification. If you create .NET Core components that target .NET Standard 2.0 then apps running .NET 4.7.1 will be able to use them. In the past, aligning Core and full Framework components was tricky as [the chart on this page shows.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)